# How to find regex matched row with stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table named **MobileOperator**. This table have following column

- ID
- OperatorName
- RegularExpression
- CountryCode

Now I want to provide a `Mobilenumber` as a parameter and want to get the row will be returned which match the `RegularExpression`.

for example I tried to write following code..But I need the correct where condition to get expected result

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMobileOperatorByNumber
    @mobileNumber nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    Select *
    From MobileOperator
    Where RegularExpression REGEXP '' ;    //error
END
```

Comment: SQL Server has no `REGEXP` operator, nor does it generally support regex.  `REGEXP` is MySQL syntax.

Comment: You can build clr-assembly with regex functionality and use it.

Comment: I suspect it is easy enough to convert into sql server syntax if you supply the pattern. Or is it entirely free-form regex?